# Excel - Array Formula to skip empty cells

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, formula

I have an array formula to fill in the cell when it contains text but I want it to ignore the cell if its blank and go to the next one. The issue I am having is that it does not do it in the order i have for example:

Range is

```
-A
-(BLANK CELL)
-(BLANK CELL)
-D
-E
-F
-(BLANK CELL)
-H
-(BLANK CELL)
```

Result from the formula

```
-A
-E
-F
-H
```

It is skipping the cells that contain letters. CAN SOMEONE HELP??

FORMULA:

`{=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF(B4:$B$12<>"",ROW(B4:$B$12)),ROW(B4:$B$12)-3)),"",INDEX(B4:$B$12,MATCH(SMALL(IF(B4:$B$12<>"",ROW(B4:$B$12)),ROW(B4:$B$12)-3),IF(B4:$B$12<>"",ROW(B4:$B$12)),0)))}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have the range as `B4:$B$12`, so because there are no $ signs around `B4` that reference changes as you drag the formula down the column.......but the formula looks a little more complex than you need so I'd rather suggest a better alternative:

Which version of Excel are you using?

In Excel 2007 or later try this version

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B$4:B$12,SMALL(IF(B$4:B$12<>"",ROW(B$4:B$12)-ROW(B$4)+1),ROWS(D$4:D4))),"")`

Assumes your first cell is `D4` (change `ROWS(D$4:D4)` part to match your actual start cell) and you are dragging the formula down the column

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

In earlier versions where `IFERROR` function is not available, you can use this version

`=IF(ROWS(D$4:D4)>COUNTA(B$4:B$12),"",INDEX(B$4:B$12,SMALL(IF(B$4:B$12<>"",ROW(B$4:B$12)-ROW(B$4)+1),ROWS(D$4:D4))))`

Comment: Yes, I am using 2007.... This is exactly what I was looking to do!Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Found a simpler and easier way, basically Excel considers all blank cells (`""`) equal, so another easy way is to select the column that contains the data and click on **Remove Duplicates** under the Data tab, this will remove (skip) all of the blank empty cells.

[image: Simple and easy way to remove blank cells from a column in Excel - by Francis Lacle]

Comment: This would delete actual duplicate values as well, but only empty cells need to be removed

Comment: Indeed, in my suggestion I assume that the range will always contain unique values for non empty cells.