# Excel: Copy every nth line from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'm trying to copy data from one sheet into another. Each data point is separated by nine rows. On the new sheet, I begin from the sixth row and I continue this for 20 rows. For example:

```
B6=Scenarios!H7
B7=Scenarios!H16
B8=Scenarios!H25
...
```

I wouldn't mind doing this manually, but I have a lot of columns to fill, based on this pattern.

```
C6=Scenarios!H8
C7=Scenarios!H17
C8=Scenarios!H26
...
```

I manually fill a couple columns and skip a couple 'Scenario' sheet rows before continuing this pattern.

```
F6=Scenarios!H11
F7=Scenarios!H20
F8=Scenarios!H29
...

E6=Scenarios!H12
E7=Scenarios!H21
...
```

I have looked around and I know that the INDIRECT or OFFSET command can help, like

```
F5=INDIRECT("Scenarios!H"&((ROW(H11)*9)))
```

or

```
F5=INDIRECT("Scenarios!H"&((ROW($H7)*1)+4))
```

Yet I'm unable to get a formula going that works correctly in a manner where I can simply copy down cells and have it fill correctly. Can anyone help me on the math for this, or otherwise provide a better solution?

Comment: Quick clarification - Do you want to literally be skipping every Nth line, or would a formula work? I have a formula that you can use that, given a range (say A1:A10), can return only those cells that have something in them. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338711/excel-array-formula-to-skip-empty-cells) for an example on what I mean. Would something like that work?

Comment: Well, it's like this:

Sheet1)

Variable A  | 1234
Variable B  | 9876

Sheet 2)
Variable A  | Variable B

Comment: Well, it's basically a normalization issue. I have various concatenation macros automatically building JSONs and various other scripts based on what I feed it. I just needed a macro or formula that'd enable to only have to change data in one place in order for it to be reflected elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

B6 = `=INDEX(Scenarios!H:H, ROWS($B$6:B6)*9-2)`

C6 = `=INDEX(Scenarios!H:H, ROWS($B$6:B6)*9-1)`

F6 = `=INDEX(Scenarios!H:H, ROWS($B$6:B6)*9+2)`

E6= `=INDEX(Scenarios!H:H, ROWS($B$6:B6)*9+3)`

Copy formulas down and you get the idea of math if you have other columns to fill.

Comment: I would recommend `INDEX(Scenerio!H:H,ROW(1:1) * 9 - 2)`  INDIRECT is volatile.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I updated my answer to an INDEX version. I originally thought of INDEX when I read the question, but then decided to just tweak his thoughts to make it work. I've gotten familiar with a lot of functions, but still learning what makes one better than another. I don't work with a lot of large sets of data to learn the hard way. That's what makes this site such a great learning tool for all levels of experience.

Comment: Thank you Sincere and Scott. I was able to use this to solve my issue. Even tested by moving columns around. Seems stable. I greatly appreciate it.