# How to hide blank rows in excel via expression?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

i have 2 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2) in excel 
**Sheet1**
Sheet1 have 2 columns A,B and 6 rows with Data. 

**Sheet2** 
Sheet2 have 1 column A, Cell A1= `if(sheet1!a1="ali", a1,"")`
same formula in 6 rows by increasing row number like in ExCel.
the formula is working well, i want only the value that match the expression not the blank rows like i show in the snippet, how can i do this?

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sheet1!A</th>
    <th>Sheet!B</th>
    <th>Sheet2!C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ali</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Irfan</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td><i>i don't want this</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Irfan</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td><i>i don't want this</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sufyan</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td><i>i don't want this</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Owais</td>
    <td>900</td>
    <td><i>i don't want this</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ali</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not just filter first sheet on ALI?

Comment: you will need an array formula that returns all non empty rows, not a simple `if` formula.

Comment: i am posting journal entries on sheet1 and on sheet2 i want only the values that match the client name?

Comment: #banana can you please show me formula on the above example!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338711/excel-array-formula-to-skip-empty-cells

Answer (score 0):

Why not use autofilter and copy? Your data needs to be set up as a table which you can do by selecting a populated cell and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd>; ensuring you have headers.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Ali"
    .Range("Table1").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    End With

End Sub
```

Or if copying to next available row use:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<==Change name appropriately
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    With wsSource.ListObjects("Table1").Range    '<==Change table name appropriately
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Ali"
        .Range("Table1").Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Data (with headers) after filter and before copy:

[image: Data]

Comment: Did this help at all?