# Excel If function Without Empty rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have Sheet with schedules of the customers and date for delivery but i have couple sheets like that.
I want to create a calendar that brings all the sheets together, so We can see everything in the calendar on the appropriate  date.
I am using this code. `=IF(CURRENT!H20:H117=E1,CURRENT!B20:B117,"")`
problem with this is, this works only on one sheet and also when it prints on the calendar I have a lot of empty rows.
I am basically looking for a better idea to approach this or a fix for the above code.
[image]
it jumps rows because where it gets the information does not have the same dates.

Comment: If you have Office 365, look into FILTER

Comment: that wouldn't work.  if i filter date 10/21 it would filter all rows from 3 to 18

Comment: if I may suggest to make it easier what if you will only have a column of your Name Company and Date and try the Pivottable.

Comment: `=FILTER(CURRENT!H20:H117,CURRENT!H20:H117=E1)` would give the results without the blanks.

Comment: Have you considered PowerQuery (Data...NewQuery...)? Join/append data from all sheets, then clear empty rows and perform anything else you need. Pretty fast too...

Comment: Another idea is to import entirely the sheets one under the other (permanently), then have a Filter (...home...editing...filter) to filter out empties and sort by date... (to properly filter empty rows you'll need a column with the info, artificial if necessary)

Comment: Data constantly changes.  I am trying to makes this automated. I was hoping to filtering it  by just codes.
=IFERROR(INDEX(CURRENT!$B$2:$B$700,SMALL(IF(CURRENT!$H$20:$I$700=CALENDAR!A$2,ROW(CURRENT!$H$20:$I$700)-1),ROW()-ROW($A$4)+1),0),"")
With this code i can now list all without spacing but since some customer has same pick up and delivery dates, it duplicates rows.
I tried Remove duplicate option but it does not work...
Im wondering if there any code that we can enter within this can find the duplicates and avoid entering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lazy Method**

you can create a second page and use an array formula as below,

=IFERROR(INDEX(B$4:B$12,SMALL(IF(B$4:B$12<>"",ROW(B$4:B$12)-ROW(B$4)+1),ROWS(D$4:D4))),"")
CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

[Excel - Array Formula to skip empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338711/excel-array-formula-to-skip-empty-cells)

**Proper Method**

=IFERROR(INDEX(CURRENT!$B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF(CURRENT!$A$1:$A$5=Sheet2!A$1,ROW(CURRENT!$A$1:$A$5)-1),ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1),0),"")
CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_3Gb-6JCzlfp768cpqGJgayRXKGOKOa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109066354093040261286&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I think this will work, but i think im doing something wrong on my side.
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(CURRENT!$H$20:$H$200,SMALL(IF(CURRENT!$H$20:$H$200=AAA!A$2,ROW(CURRENT!$H$20:$H$200)-1),ROW()-ROW($A$4)+1),0),"")), 1, 1)
when i enter this code i get #NAME?

Comment: We actually made it work with this code down here.  thank you so much.
But one more question please.
H has pick up dates. and I has delivery dates. So sometimes we pickup and deliver them the same date.  So we get duplicate entries with this code. is any way to avoid the duplicates?
=IFERROR(INDEX(CURRENT!$B$2:$B$200,SMALL(IF(CURRENT!$H$20:$I$200=CALENDAR!A$2,ROW(CURRENT!$H$20:$I$200)-1),ROW()-ROW($A$4)+1),0),"")

Comment: i meant ( duplicate in customer names )